# Word describing the "finiteness" of something

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm trying to find another term which means "finiteness". To me, it sounds too clumsy. Part of my mind gesticulates wildly toward a "-cy" suffix word to describe this, like "captaincy" or "valency"... but of course, "finicy" sounds a tad ridiculous and there is obviously no such word.

Even if I did use "finiteness", I feel it would suggest too strongly the finite aspect, where as "infiniteness" would just be silly. Obviously, the word should be neutral, but describe the polarisation between finite and infinite. Just as "colour" is a totally neutral word not suggesting *any* particular colour.

Suggestions?

Comment: I think it wouldn't be too localized if you didn't mention the programming task.

Comment: I had to decode that down to "I think it's too localised because you mentioned the programming task". Ah, the fun to be had on english.stackexchange...

Comment: I didn't vote to close, since I think it's a valid question.  All the same, we tend to shy away from questions which ask for a good word for a variable name, because they are often very localized to the specific programming situation.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a word that describes the characteristic of having an (in)finite measurement... But then it sort of depends on what you're measuring: Do you need to describe a cardinality? Or it's magnitude? Or it's boundedness? It's quantifiability? Are we talking about size? length? continuity?

Comment: @Nick: See the newest development in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Finitude](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/finitude)* is a word, <s>though not as common</s>.  Actually, scratch that; check out the [Ngram graph](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=limitedness%2Cboundedness%2Cfiniteness%2Cfinitude&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=limitedness%2Cboundedness%2Cfiniteness%2Cfinitude&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

So it's actually more common than *finiteness*, *boundedness*, and *limitedness* put together.

Comment: According to the definition I just found, although I prefer "finitude" to "finiteness", the latter is more commonly used in maths and logic. I have decided I like this word enough to use it in my code, if only in it's similarity to magnitude, which is nicely neutral.

Comment: See the edit.  I'm surprised.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not, given the clumsiness of the former. However you appear much more well-read than I.

Comment: *Finiteness* and *finitude* aren't really words that pop up that often, though, so I couldn't tell you off the top of my head which was more popular.  I just guessed at *finiteness* because it seems like obscurer words gravitate toward that ending, for some reason.  I have seen both *finitude* and *finiteness* used before, though.

Comment: Finitude is the first term that came to mind when I read this.

Answer (score 3):

Can you use just plain *[limit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/limit)*, *[bound](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bounds)s* or *[boundary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boundary)*?
Limit in particular seems to be a neutral category for numbers, indicating neither infinite nor finite.

> **limit** *n*:  *the ultimate extent, degree, or amount of something*
>
> It may also be used in the plural, *limits*.

Comment: *Bounded* is good in a lot of circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

I could list another word:

> Limitedness: The state of being limited to a certain boundary

Comment: Though this is just as clumsy as *finiteness*, so it may not appeal to the OP.

Comment: Seems there are no unbiased options...